# Is it possible to change imei number in android phone

Tags: android

I am making a testing tool, i have got the imei number but is it possible to change the imei number in simple or via NDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to change an IMEI is hardware/system dependent, and it is - at least in (large) parts of the world - [illegal to do](http://www.met.police.uk/mobilephone/reprogramming.htm).

I think you could safely assume there is no API for it in the NDK.

Comment: You do not always need an API if there are vulnerabilities in the platform. This is a non-answer. Joachim, delete it at once!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible as it is uniquely tied to the given handset.

If the handset has a modded ROM, that can return a fake IMEI, but otherwise this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible ... if you know how to flash the "ROM" e.g. with cyagenmod instead of android - or not ?!
There are apps with names like rom-manager or similiar.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, with various tools this is going to depend on device make.model..the xiaomi/realmi/redmi's I believe all have custom tools for this, as well as there are msm-tool style generic flash tools for Qualcomm, ect. Doing a search around places that carry such tools such as halabtech, 4pda, Android forums/developers, you will run across many but it's going to depend on your device whether it will fly or not. Also as stated in some countries it's illegal to do such as that's how they blacklist devices that are balance owed or reported lost are stolen or whatever on a carrier. That said there are some devices like the jelly phones and whatnot that come with a tool for doing this out of the box you can change it anytime you need. And then there are some of these tools exist for the purpose of corrupt IMEI numbers registering as 0 or not showing at all after a flash or bad fire hose reset or anything. So most of these tools are going to fall into that category, ie fixing your original imei if damaged. The new and neat thing you'll find looking around though, Google around for xposed sim number changer, this thing can fix or change the actual phone number number the one that you dial to call it, all from the phone itself,  from inside Android with xposed and it's not, like most things exposed, temporary or a spoof, the repo states like if you don't want to use this on your main device or root your main device this is completely doable from an old device pop your sim, change or set the number, and pop it in the main device that's unrooted and it will keep changes consistently across devices that don't even have xposed. it physically writes the changes to the card itself, however it's not going to be able to change values like Sim number or Sim serial number which can be spoofed on an app basis or globally depending on if you want to hook everything in system product and vendor along the way with something like Android faker or gergit xposed, but that's just going to fool specific applications not the telephony manager which is the Boss of All bosses when it comes to reading and verifying profiles. You'll find that looking through a few of these DRM wildvine magisk modules and in one case of a xiaomi device there was an app released for Android 11 that would fix it and show it as DRM level 1 if you were rooted in bootloader unlocked you can still watch Netflix on full quality HD. And I looked through the code the best I could and it looks like the check part of it done inside Android is going to take your IMEI number, run it through a hash salt encrypt it 90 different ways starting with DER/PEM, encryption, it looks like there's a specific vendor crypto  jar/package inside vendor, and that's going to be based on your manufacturer of your phone Motorola Samsung whatever will have its own crypto packages and it's going to take that and generate a key that will be specific to your device and it will check against the telephony manager on boot for said key to report whether or not your bootloader is unlocked.. and these apps seem to either stop the encryption itself and keep track of the key or just report good status to the manager at the end when it's called I'm not sure it gets lots of blurry with all the encrypting going on looking at dex/smali ;p

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).